# What's the difference in running Flask on an Apache server using mod_wsgi vs a reverse proxy

Tags: apache, flask, mod-wsgi

I'm having trouble understanding what the difference is between running Flask on an Apache server using mod_wsgi vs running a Flask server in the background and having the apache server be a reverse proxy for it. I suppose my confusion stems from the fact that I'm not really understanding what mod_wsgi is doing to Flask. What I'm understanding is that with mod_wsgi, the Flask app actually gets run by apache, I think. Any help clearing this up would be appreciated.